Why did potted Flamboyant stop growing?
I live in the Caribbean and I've had a flamboyan plant in a 22"(H) x 26"(W) pot for many years now, and it seems that it's not growing or expanding anymore. It's not dying, and it seems to be doing well, but after a certain point it hasn't grown larger. It got stuck.
The plant itself is about 55" high, with 3 branches coming out of the soil: one of the branches is about 2" wide and another one is about 3.5" wide since it has 3 other branches.
What can I do promote its growth? Usually, it's hibernating at this time of the year.

pictures please

Why would you encourage growth during dormancy? Isn't the pot stunting growth as with a bonsai?

What is Your goal for the tree? Get taller? Get bushier? Grow more leaves and branches? Flower more often? Make sure it doesn't die?
